# Diagnosing Cause of 100% CPU Usage by "System" Process

Tags: resource-leak, xperf

I have a Windows server application, implemented in C++ using the Win32 API, that does a lot of serial and TCP/IP communication.  As it runs, CPU usage gradually increases, until it reaches 100%.  Task Manager indicates that most (>75%) of the CPU usage is by the "System" process.  If I kill my server process, then CPU usage returns to normal.

Are there any "easy" ways to diagnose exactly what the problem is?

I suspect that I/O connections are being opened and never closed, so the OS is spending more and more time servicing those requests, but I'd like to verify that is the case before I try to fix the problem.

---

Update: After playing around with `xperf`, I've found that the System process is spending more than half of its time in `ntoskrnl.exe!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire`. I don't know anything about this, but the name of the function suggests to me that there might be a deadlock/contention issue.

Other functions that System is using a lot include `NETIO.SYS!FilterMatchEnum`, `NETIO.SYS!MatchConditionOverlap`, `NETIO.SYS!IsFilterVisible`, and `MpNWMon.sys!NetFlowUpendByCompletionHandle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend checking out the [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) tools if you haven't already.

One tool there I like very much is the [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) tool, which shows you all the files that are open in the system.

Another one which seems directly applicable to your scenario is [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx), which allows you to dump process information when a given process exceeds x% of CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

Use process explorer, but open your own process rather than the System process. The system process is likely just responding to your requests. Since you don't have the code for it, you are going to have a hard time knowing what it's doing

for your own process:

- Open the performance tab that shows
  the handle counts etc,
- Open the tcp-ip tab that shows the
  connections.
- Check also the pane on
  the lower half of the process
  explorer for your process showing
  events, files, etc..

Hopefully you can see what resource is being over used from one of those.

Portmon may also be worth a try to see if the activity is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using sysinternal's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx), which should show you the status of TCP connections and serial port activity.

If you see a correlation between that and the CPU usage then you have a good lead.

Answer (score 1):

Userdump.  Get a userdump of your process when it is in this situation.  Then load the dump in winDbg and see what it is doing.  One really useful command is !runaway. This will tell you which threads are using the most CPU.  Then look at those threads to see what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

What's your handle count - if that's rising, it would point to something not being closed.

Comment: Thanks, but handle count stays constant.